# kafka connector jdbc-sink syntax error at the end

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, docker-compose, debezium

i have an issue about jdbc-sink with this arch.

> postgres1 ---> kafka ---> postgres2

the producer working fine, but the consumer has an error :

> connect_1    | org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.RetriableException:
>   java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0
>   INSERT INTO "customers" ("id") VALUES (1) ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE
>   SET  was aborted: ERROR: syntax error at end of input connect_1    |
>   Position: 77  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.

this is my source.json

```
{
"name": "src-table",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "postgres1_container",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "database.user": "postgres",
    "database.password": "postgres",
    "database.dbname": "postgres",
    "database.whitelist": "postgres",
    "database.server.name": "postgres1",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.inventory",
    "transforms": "route",
    "transforms.route.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.route.regex": "([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)",
    "transforms.route.replacement": "$3"
}
```

and this my jdbc-sink.json

```
{
    "name": "jdbc-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "customers",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://postgres2_container:5432/postgres?user=postgres&password=postgres",
        "transforms": "unwrap",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope",
        "auto.create": "true",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "pk.fields": "id",
        "pk.mode": "record_value"
    }
}
```

debezium/zookeeper : 0.9

debezium/kafka:0.9

debezium/postgres:9.6

debezium/connect:0.9

PostgreSQL JDBC Driver 42.2.5

Kafka Connect JDBC 5.2.1

i tried to downgrade jdbc driver and confluent kafka connect but still have the same error

Comment: I post a question similar to yours can you look ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68575974/kafka-connect-sink-error-creating-sink-connector-do-update-set-was-aborted

Answer (score 0):

solve, the problem coz while i create a table in postgres1, i did not set the `id` to a PK value

Comment: Can you explain how you created the table in postgres1 and set the `id` to a PK value? Thanks!

Comment: sorry man, i already forgot about it. @David

Comment: No problem, I think the PK part refered to something like this `CREATE TABLE test(id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, value VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL)` (https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-serial/).

Comment: Actually my problem was different, slightly stupid and related to missing topics `config/offset/status.storage.topic` in the Kafka Connector configuration that could not be auto-created (https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.0/connect/userguide.html#distributed-configuration-properties). The error message was very misleading for me. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Same issue,

I think this is an issue on JDBC Connector, when the table has only primary key columns and no other column there is nothing to update and therefore the statement syntax is wrong as it always excepts a column to update after the on-conflict.

One solution could be to add additional columns to that table, of course this is not a solution but a quick and dirty workaround.

Another solution is to upgrade the JDBC, I tested the same with kafka-connect-jdbc-10.4.0 and seems that this issue is no longer present.